# Software computing dimension and degree

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, projective-geometry, computer-algebra, magma

Assume a projective scheme $X_{k_1,\dots,k_r}\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ is given as the set of common solutions of homogeneous polynomials $F_1(x_0,\dots,x_n),\dots,F_s(x_0,\dots,x_n)$, where the $F_i$ depends on parameters $k_1,\dots,k_r$ varying in the base field.

Does there exist a computer algebra software that can compute the dimension and the degree of $X_{k_1,\dots,k_r}$ as functions of $k_1,\dots,k_r$?

Comment: I think dimension and degree follow, if a grobner base is known. So the problem is to compute all grobner bases appearing for certain polynomial equalities and inequalities in the paramers $k_1,\ldots,k_r$. I did not verify this by doing an example computation myself, but https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/4-0-3/sing_955.htm and https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/4-0-3/sing_931.htm#SEC1006 seem to provide, what you sought. (Libraries compregb_lib and grobcov_lib).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) (tagged in your question), [Singular](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/) (cited in  Jürgen Böhm's comment), there's also [Macaulay2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/).  AFAIK, all provide methods for calculating the required Gröbner basis.

Comment: Could you give a reference for Macaulay2 of a documentation page where computing gröbner bases *with parameters* is described? Note that this is an extension of the usual concept of gröbner base: If you have $R=\mathbb{Q}[a][x]$ as basering with parameter $a$ and a polynom $f = a x^2 + x + 1$ then a gröbner base with parameters would give a list $[a \neq 0, f]$ as a first base and $[a=0, x+1]$ as a second base. This is useful in many applications, but I have not found a command in Macaulay2 to do this. The same applies to your Magma link.